# Computing repeatControls property of a repeat generate designer error

Tags: eclipse, xpages, repeat

I am trying to compute the repeatControls property of a repeat but get an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{javascript:10}">
        <xp:this.repeatControls><![CDATA[${javascript:"true"}]]>    </xp:this.repeatControls>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

**Here is the error**

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not generate a .java file for the page /test.xsp: Could not find the runtime class for the tag xp:repeat, due to a problem invoking com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspDataIterator.getJavaClass(class com.ibm.xsp.page.parse.types.FacesInstance).  test.xsp    test.nsf/XPages line 1  com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.designerproblem

Is this some kind of bug in DDE or am doing it wrong?
I have tried putting the "true" without quotes as well

I am using notes 9 beta 1

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Repeat (`xp:repeat`) control specifies the following tooltip for the `repeatControls` property.

**Repeat Controls (boolean:repeatControls)**
*Specifies if the controls should be created multiple times or the single set of controls should be iterated over multiple times.*

The `repeatControls` property accepts boolean values; specifically either `"true"` or `"false"`. In Domino Designer from the All Properties View despite the presence of the blue diamond (indicating it can be computed), this property should not be computed.

At design time, the `repeatControls` property value is used to inform how the compiled XPage is generated hence invalid values prevent this from succeeding; this is the error being reported by Domino Designer and has been logged with the team with reference "*DEGN95SMPT*".